# create compute instance in azure machine learning workspace terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using terraform module `machine_learning_workspace` to create machine learning workspace in Azure. Relevent code for that is as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_machine_learning_workspace" "example" {
  name                    = "${var.ML_workspace_name}"
  location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.azurem_application_insight.id
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  storage_account_id      = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to create a compute instance within this workspace. terraform does not support this or I am not able to find it in docs.

are there other ways to automate its creation?

Comment: Nope, tf does not support it as of today https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6827

Comment: ahh.. I could not find any azcli commands to do that either. sad. @silent Thanks. :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/computetarget/create?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: @silent isn't that different from compute instance?

Comment: ah sorry, yeah you are correct. Guess then you can only automate that through the python SDK?!

Comment: Thanks will look into it. definitely a viable option.